# Creating csv from an XML that has repeating tags

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to normalize an xml file that has a parent tag with repeating child tags. Please see a sample of the data below:

```html
<GeneralQuestions>
    <HeaderText>Pain Management Assessment</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Pain assessment</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>Yes</QuestionAnswer>
    <HeaderText>Activities of Daily Living</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Patient walks</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>With Some Help</QuestionAnswer>
    <Score>1</Score>
    <HeaderText>Pain Management Assessment</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Patient consents to having Pain Management Assessment screening completed.</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>Patient accepts</QuestionAnswer>
    <HeaderText>Activities of Daily Living</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Patient gets dressed</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>With Some Help</QuestionAnswer>
    <Score>1</Score>
</GeneralQuestions>
```

You'll observe that the child tags in "GeneralQuestions" are getting repeated with the child tag "Score" being optional. I am trying to convert it to a normalized form in which each set of child tags form a row, like shown below:

1. HeaderText, QuestionText,QuestionAnswer,Score
2. HeaderText, QuestionText,QuestionAnswer,Score
3. HeaderText, QuestionText,QuestionAnswer,Score

If the "Score" is missing, I want null value. I am using python 3.7 and xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse to parse the data. Please let me know how I can normalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here an incomplete answer that can help you using `numpy` to number the tags. I assumed some structure which is same. Say we have

```
XML = """<GeneralQuestions>
    <HeaderText>Pain Management Assessment</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Pain assessment</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>Yes</QuestionAnswer>
    <HeaderText>Activities of Daily Living</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Patient walks</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>With Some Help</QuestionAnswer>
    <Score>1</Score>
    <HeaderText>Pain Management Assessment</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Patient consents to having Pain Management Assessment screening completed.</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>Patient accepts</QuestionAnswer>
    <HeaderText>Activities of Daily Living</HeaderText>
    <QuestionText>Patient gets dressed</QuestionText>
    <QuestionAnswer>With Some Help</QuestionAnswer>
    <Score>1</Score>
</GeneralQuestions>"""
```

And we create a tree with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(XML)
```

Than with using `numpy` we can create an index with

```
import numpy as np
index_of_score = np.cumsum( [ e.tag == 'HeaderText' for e in tree.getchildren() ] )
```

Now with help of the `index_of_score` you can create a dictionary with indexed tags, and possible value

```
{ "{}_{}".format(a.tag,i) : a.text for i,a in zip(index_of_score, tree.getchildren() ) }
```

which will give you

```
{'HeaderText_1': 'Pain Management Assessment',
 'QuestionText_1': 'Pain assessment',
 'QuestionAnswer_1': 'Yes',
 'HeaderText_2': 'Activities of Daily Living',
 'QuestionText_2': 'Patient walks',
 'QuestionAnswer_2': 'With Some Help',
 'Score_2': '1',
 'HeaderText_3': 'Pain Management Assessment',
 'QuestionText_3': 'Patient consents to having Pain Management Assessment screening completed.',
 'QuestionAnswer_3': 'Patient accepts',
 'HeaderText_4': 'Activities of Daily Living',
 'QuestionText_4': 'Patient gets dressed',
 'QuestionAnswer_4': 'With Some Help',
 'Score_4': '1'}
```

Depending on your desired output you can cherry pick the values you need. Say the above dictionary is `dict_output`, python has the nice `dict_output.get("Score_1", None)` which will give you either the value or in this case `None` which might help you in processing the data.

Comment: Thanks @user3184950. I found another way to process the file.

Answer (score 0):

I created a context from the XML file:

```
xmlIter=ET.iterparse('C:\\Users\\ANAND_RA\\Documents\\Project\\XXXXXXX_MA_05042020_0.xml', events=('start','end'))
context=iter(xmlIter)
```

Then I used a for loop to parse through each tag:

```
for eachEvent, eachElement in context:
```

The final step (the most important one) is to process the tag "GeneralQuestions" under the for loop:

```
if eachElement.tag=='GeneralQuestions' and eachEvent=='start':
        GQstart=True
        GQcount=0
        GQlist=[]
        GQDataList=[]
    if eachElement.tag=='HeaderText' and GQstart and eachEvent=='start':
        if GQcount!=0:
            if len(GQlist)<6:
                GQlist.extend([None,1,today,today])
            else:
                GQlist.extend([1,today,today])
            GQDataList.append(tuple(GQlist))
        GQcount+=1
        GQlist=[]
        GQlist.extend([nextDLMemberSK,GQcount,eachElement.text])
    if eachElement.tag=='QuestionText' and GQstart and eachEvent=='start':
        GQlist.append(eachElement.text)
    if eachElement.tag=='QuestionAnswer' and GQstart and eachEvent=='start':
        GQlist.append(eachElement.text)
    if eachElement.tag=='Score' and GQstart and eachEvent=='start':
        GQlist.append(eachElement.text)
    if eachElement.tag=='GeneralQuestions' and eachEvent=='end' and GQcount!=0:
        if len(GQlist)==5:
            GQlist.extend([None,1,today,today])
        else:
            GQlist.extend([1,today,today])
        GQDataList.append(tuple(GQlist))
    if eachElement.tag=='GeneralQuestions' and eachEvent=='end' and len(GQDataList)>0:
#         print(GQDataList)
        cur1.executemany(SQL_INS_INOV_GENERALQ,GQDataList)
```

Processing an XML is quite different from processing a json file. In json, the data inspection is more flexible. However, in xml data you have to inspect the tags as it comes in the for loop.